# php array to SQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays

```
$array = array
        (
            53 => array('num' => 20,'name' => 'aaa'),
            10 => array('num' => 20,'name' => 'bbb')
        );
```

$sql ="INSENT INTO data(id,num,name) VALUES`('53','20','aaa'),('10','20','bbb')` ";

How to convert $array to `('53','20','aaa'),('10','20','bbb')` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[implode()](https://www.php.net/implode) can help you do this, though you will need to loop through and apply it to each individual array:

```
 $resultStrings = array();
 foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
    $subarrayString = "('$key','" . implode($values, "','") . "')";
    $resultStrings[] = $subarrayString;
 }
 
 $result = implode($resultStrings, ",");
```

Comment: `implode($array, "','")` -> `implode($subarray, "','")` thanks

Comment: Yep, sorry, missed that one before I posted. Just updated my answer.

Comment: I like the second implode there! Watch out, though, the poster wanted the key of the array in there as well. You'd need to loop $array as $key=>$subarray and concatenate the key before the imploded subarray

Comment: Very true! Man, I was not on it when I submitted that. Edited again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this using a prepared statement and a simple loop, eg

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO data(id, num, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $num);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $name);

foreach ($array as $id => $vals) {
    $num = $vals['num'];
    $name = $vals['name'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Won't this execute once per array? I'd avoid any more roundtrips to the database than strictly needed.

Comment: This will hit the DB once per outer array element, however the statement is *prepared* and thus bind values/arguments are communicated in reduced traffic and the DB has already parsed the SQL statement.  It might come down to 6|half-dozen/one-or-the-other scenario, but this method is well-known pattern and compatible across DB platforms vs. the compound values for a MySQL insert statement.

Comment: @Justin not to mention the benefits of using parameter binding.

Answer (score 0):

loop through them using foreach:

```
$result = '';
foreach ($array as $key=>$subarray) {
    $result .= "('$key'";
    foreach ($subarray as $el) {
        $result .= ",'$el'";
    }
    $result .= "),";
}
//get rid of the trailing comma
$result = substr($result,0,-1);
```

et voilá