# problem with array increment

Tags: php

I have array with alphanumeric key values..While filling array on particular condition I have filled array key with `empty` word. Now I want if on key `empty` is arises array should be increment with one position, so that that value is not stored in db. Simply want to skip that key and move to next.

```
foreach( $inputs as $key => $value) {

if(key($inputs)=="empty"){ $inputs[]++; }
else{   echo "<strong>$key</strong> Singer <strong>$value</strong></br>";
//INSERT Query;    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting elements for an array use:

```
unset($inputs[$key]);
```

For skipping, perhaps the most obvious is:

```
if(key($inputs) !== "empty") {
   //..
}
```

Note: you can insert multiple rows with one query, it might be better to do that.. build an array containing the rows "(value1,value2,...)" and use `implode`

Comment: Note exact match, but this should help understand the concept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300552/php-array-to-sql

Answer (score 1):

you perhaps mean to use something like a conditional [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) inside your foreach loop:

```
foreach( $inputs as $key => $value)
{
  if ($key === "empty")
  {
    continue; # at next element in $inputs
  }
  echo "<strong>$key</strong> Singer <strong>$value</strong></br>";
  //INSERT Query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you want, but:

```
foreach( $inputs as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'empty') continue;

    // insert query
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`continue`](http://php.net/continue);

Change this:

```
if(key($inputs)=="empty"){ $inputs[]++; }
```

To:

```
if(key($inputs)=="empty"){ continue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
foreach( $inputs as $key => $value) {
if($key == "empty"){ 
    $inputs[$key]++; 
}
else{   
    echo "<strong>$key</strong> Singer <strong>$value</strong></br>";
    //INSERT Query;    
}
```

Comment: is this skip particular key and jump to next?

Comment: that will increment the value for that key

Comment: That Wat I had confusion. as it will increase value of key by one. N I have alphabetical key.